# Is cyclopropyl methyl carbanion also exceptionally stable?

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance

I know that cyclopropyl methyl carbocation is exceptionally stable and in fact more stable than benzyl carbocation but I was wondering if it was the same case with cyclopropyl methyl carbanion. Is it also more stable than benzyl carbanion?

Answer (score 1):

Sigma resonance only works on cyclopropyl methyl carbocation (and its cyclopropyl derivatives). So I don't think that cyclopropyl methyl carbanion will be exceptionally stable.

Comment: Could you explain why sigma resonance only applies for cyclopropyl methyl carbocation.